Bound an operator to get a contraction
In my master I need to study the existence of solution of a certain ODE. The way to do that is to use a Banach fixed point type of argument. Therefore, I need to define an appropriate operator with the adequate norms and then prove that we actually have a contraction. I manage to prove the existence of solution in a simplified case but I can't prove it in the general case. Let me explain in more details.
Let us define the operator $A$ acting on the $C^1$ function $g$ such that
$$A[g](t) = \int_{t_0}^{t - t^\alpha} g(u) \frac{u}{t(t - u)}du,$$
for $t_0$ a fixed number that can be chosen arbitrarily large and $\alpha > 0$ arbitrarily close to $1$. If I set the norms
$$\|g\|_1 = \sup_{[t_0, +\infty)} |g(t)|t^{3/2} \log(t) < + \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \|A[g]\|_2 = \sup_{[t_0, +\infty)} |A[g](t)|t^{3/2} < +\infty.$$
I manage to prove, after some computation, that
$$\|A[g]\|_{2} \le C  \|g\|_1 \left((1 - \alpha) + \frac{1}{\log(t_0)}\right).$$
Taking $\alpha$ close to $1$ and $t_0$ large enough gives us (after a bit of work) the desired contraction and incidentally the existence of $g$.
Now, I would like additionally $g$ to satisfy some Hölder-continuity property. More precisely, for
$$[g]_{\gamma,1} = \sup_{t \in [t_0, +\infty), \\t/2 \le s \le t}\frac{|g(t) - g(s)|}{(t - s)^{\gamma}}t^{3/2 + \gamma} \log(t) < + \infty \quad \text{and} \quad [A[g]]_{\gamma,2}= \sup_{t \in [t_0, +\infty), \\t/2 \le s \le t}\frac{|A[g](t) - A[g](s)|}{(t - s)^{\gamma}}t^{3/2 + \gamma} < +\infty $$
for some $\gamma \in (0,1)$, I would like to find some inequality of the form
$$\|A[g]\|_2 + [A[g]]_{\gamma, 2} \le C \left\{\|g\|_1 + [g]_{\gamma, 1}\right\} \left((1 - \alpha) + \frac{1}{\log(t_0)}\right),$$
but I can't find something like that.
As I already treated the simpler case with $\|A[g]\|_2$, I only have to consider the term $[A[g]]_{\gamma, 2}$ and prove an inequality like
$$|A[g](t) - A[g](s)| \le C\frac{\|g\|_{1} + [g]]_{\gamma, 1}}{t^{3/2 + \gamma}}(t - s)^\gamma \left((1 - \alpha) + \frac{1}{\log(t_0)}\right)$$
but the term $|A[g](t) - A[g](s)|$ is quite messy to deal with and I couldn't fine such inequality. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
